# Send notification to notification center in mountain lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications

How would I be able to send a notification to the Notification Center in Mountain Lion from objective-c in my mac app? (not to be confused with nsnotificationcenter).  I would like a link to a sample project or sample code posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `NSUserNotification` class. Once you have set it up, you can schedule it through the `NSUserNotificationCenter` class which will then handle the presentation to the user.

Comment: The url for NSUserNotification is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012260